# Multiprocessing Pooling and Lightgbm

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiprocessing, data-science, lightgbm

i am trying to train completely independent tasks using multiprocess pooling in python, which lightgbm for training(i am not sure if this is relevant for problem). Here is the code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np

def functionToParallize(splitnumber=2):

    data = load_breast_cancer()
    X = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
    y = pd.Series(data.target)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    folds = KFold(splitnumber)
    results = lgb.cv({}, lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train), folds=folds,metrics=['rmse'])
    return results
```

to parallelize i use multiprocessing pooling with say 2 pool workers. But the it's really inefficient as it takes 1000 times more time to finish a task with 2 pools as it takes with just one. For eg.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import psutil
print(psutil.cpu_count())
```

output

> 4

```
starttime=time.time()
pool = Pool(2)
multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(functionToParallize) for i in [3]]
p=[res.get() for res in multiple_results]
print((time.time()-starttime)/60)
```

output

> 0.007067755858103434

but with two pools

```
starttime=time.time()
pool = Pool(2)
multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(functionToParallize) for i in [2,3]]
p=[res.get() for res in multiple_results]
print((time.time()-starttime)/60)
```

> 1.026989181836446

This is actually not the original task, but i am doing something similar there. But for that single task takes about a minute and pool 2 process never ends there at all.
Am i doing something wrong here ?? I am doing this on a jupyter notebook, If that's relevant.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Instead of getting into so much trouble... You can work around by using the num_threads to half of your cpu counts. By default num_threads is -1 which allows lgbm to run on all cores present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason, it's because lgb's internal threading conflicts with custom pooling. Forcing lgb not to use threading helps.

```
results = lgb.cv({'num_threads':1}, lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train), folds=folds,metrics=['rmse'])
```

Thanks Manzi,
Cheers

Comment: Another option is to set the num_threads parameter directly in the predict function. I haven't tested, but I think you'd want to use all threads when training. https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1534